# Netlogo: How to randomly select out of all neighbor patches that have a higher elevation?

Tags: netlogo

I want my turtles to be able to assess which neighbour patches have a higher elevation than the current patch and then randomly select one of these higher elevation patches to move to.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `uphill` primitive [i.e. dictionary](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/5.0/docs/dictionary.html#uphill) with something like

```
ask turtles [
   uphill elevation
]
```

EDIT
You can use something like

```
ask tutles [
 let myelevPatch elevation patch-here
 let higherpatches patches in neighbors with [elevation > myelevPatch]
 move-to one-of higherpatches
]
```

Comment: I thought about this but am I correct in thinking that the uphill primitive only selects the surrounding patch with the highest elevation and not a patch with simply a higher elevation than the current patch?

Comment: You can actually access patch variables of `patch-here` directly from the turtle's own context, so you could just do: `let higher-patches neighbors with [elevation > [elevation] of myself]`. If you do not, you will need to change your solution to `let myelevPatch [elevation] of patch-here`. You will also need to add an `any?` check to your patch set in case it returns `nobody`.